# I need to subtract from different baseline value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to create a new column similar to `newvar`. I need to subtract the values of group 1 from group 1 at the respective times and then the values of group 2 from group 1 at the respective times. The base values are of group 1 at the respective time.

```
       id group time var newvar
    1   1     1    0   0      0
    2   1     1    1   1      0
    3   1     1    2   5      0
    4   1     2    0   1      1
    5   1     2    1   2      1
    6   1     2    2   3     -2
    7   2     1    0   0      0
    8   2     1    1   2      0
    9   2     1    2   4      0
    10  2     2    0   1      1
    11  2     2    1   2      0
    12  2     2    2   5      1
```

Comment: Could you show what your expected output looks like? It'll help people to give a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, time) %>%
  mutate(result = var - var[1])

# # A tibble: 12 x 6
# # Groups:   id, time [6]
#       id group  time   var newvar result
#    <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
#  1     1     1     0     0      0      0
#  2     1     1     1     1      0      0
#  3     1     1     2     5      0      0
#  4     1     2     0     1      1      1
#  5     1     2     1     2      1      1
#  6     1     2     2     3     -2     -2
#  7     2     1     0     0      0      0
#  8     2     1     1     2      0      0
#  9     2     1     2     4      0      0
# 10     2     2     0     1      1      1
# 11     2     2     1     2      0      0
# 12     2     2     2     5      1      1
```

The corresponding solution with `ave()` in `stats`:

```
within(df, result <- ave(var, id, time, FUN = function(x) x - x[1]))
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
time = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L), 
var = c(0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L), 
newvar = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, -2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R one-liner using higher-order functions:

```
do.call("c", Map(function(x){x - x[1]}, with(df, split(var, paste0(id, time)))))
```